# addDoc function not returning a response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to insert a document in an existing collection in my Firestore DB, i tried every solution suggested but still not working...

**Firestore rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write, read: if true; // temporary rule to allow all writes
    }
  }
}
```

**Firebase Config file:**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore'
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app)
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { db, storage }
```

**My Insert Function:**

```
async function insertDoc() {
    const data = { name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@example.com' };
    const myCollectionRef = collection(db, 'restore');

    await addDoc(myCollectionRef, data)
    .then((docRef) => {
        console.log('Document written with ID: ', docRef.id);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error adding document: ', error);
     });
    }
```

How my **Firestore DB** looks like:

[image: View Image]

I tried `insertDoc()` function i created, and i expected data to be **inserted** to my **Firestore DB**.

Comment: Please update your question to include the error message that you are getting from .catch, so that we may be able to assist you.

Comment: I don't get any error message nor success message, the function runs but addDoc() does nothing

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you've tried using the official doc of firestore however you mixed it up a little bit.

In your insert function, you are using await which is the right way to add premises (More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)).

However, you're also using .then() which is used to add premises for a fetch() for example. You will have for a fecth() :

```
fetch("https://api.com/getProduct")
  .then(res => console.log(res.json())
  .catch(err => console.error(err)
```

In an async function the best way to add premises is :

```
async function insertDoc() {
    const data = { name: 'John Doe', email: 'john@example.com' };
    const myCollectionRef = collection(db, 'restore');

    try {
       const docRef = await addDoc(myCollectionRef, data);
       console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id)
    } catch (error) {
       console.error(Error adding document: ', error);
    }
}
```

You can find more information in [the official doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_7) but be careful when you select a version, you have to click on "Web version 9" as it seems that you're using this version of firestore

Comment: Already tried using try..catch but it didn't work, the problem isn't in promises i guess

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I downgraded to Firebase version 7.24.0 and updated my code to match the version (app initialization, syntax...) and now it works perfectly!